# How to continue to use factor where one level is missing (has been removed)?

Tags: r, r-factor

I'm working with a set of Fitbit data that I've downloaded and it has a list of weekdays that I'm trying to order properly. Now, the current data set has no "Fridays", but I want the factors to include it regardless.

How can I continue to factor the Weekdays, as 1-7 even if there are only 6 weekdays in the data set?

```
file<-choose.files()
   slp<-data.frame(read.csv(file))

   wkdaylevels<-c("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday")

    slp$FellAsleepAt<-strptime(slp$FellAsleepAt, format="%B %e, %Y at %I:%M%p")
    slp$AwokeAt<-strptime(slp$AwokeAt,format="%B %e, %Y at %I:%M%p")
    slp$TotalTimeSlept<-gsub("h ",":",slp$TotalTimeSlept)
    slp$TotalTimeSlept<-gsub("m","",slp$TotalTimeSlept)
    slp$TimeAsleep<-as.numeric(difftime(slp$AwokeAt,slp$FellAsleepAt))
    slp$Date<-as.Date(slp$FellAsleepAt, format="%M/%D/%Y")
    slp$DayofWeek<-as.factor(weekdays(slp$Date),levels=wkdaylevels)



    ggplot(slp,aes(x=DayofWeek,y=TimeAsleep))+
        geom_point()
```

Data here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Vdgmtwx0vNKDKEZFMEGAWQ58H66ia-xjI0evR7idfkc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: This sounds contradictory: do you want to remove unused levels or do you want to continue to use factors with a missing level?

Comment: Use factors with a missing level, I believe is what I'm getting at.

Comment: is the problem specifically with the graph? It seems like your data already has all the levels you require

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Answer: Use `factor` not `as.factor`**

The function `as` coerces an object to a class. In your case, `as.<type>` coerces to a type (factor for you).  The function `factor` is used to encode an object as a factor. The key difference is that `as.factor` does not allow a levels parameter, whereas `factor` does.

If you examine the source code of each function, you will see that `as.factor` does the coercion by using the unique levels of the object as its levels. `factor` does this if the `levels=` parameter is not specified, but allows the input of levels.

For example:

```
x <- 1:6
x2 <- factor(x, levels= 1:7)
levels(x2)
[1] "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7"
x2 <- as.factor(x, levels= 1:7) # in this case, levels won't be evaluated due to lazy evaluation
Error in as.factor(x, levels = 1:7) : unused argument (levels = 1:7)
```

TBH, I'm not sure why your R session isn't giving you this error. Are you using R 3.2.3?

Answer (score 2):

Use `levels<-` (`?levels` for help):

```
wdays <- as.factor(c("Sunday", "Monday"))
wkdaylevels<-c("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday")
levels(wdays) <- wkdaylevels
wdays
# [1] Monday Sunday
# Levels: Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday
```

And if you want to drop unused levels, you can use

```
droplevels(wdays)
# [1] Monday Sunday
# Levels: Sunday Monday
```

or

```
factor(wdays)
# [1] Monday Sunday
# Levels: Sunday Monday
```

Comment: Following that though, it's reordering the existing Weekdays and they're becoming offset.

Comment: Before adding in `levels(wdays) <- wkdaylevels` the weekday is true, meaning 7/30 is a Thursday, but when applied, it changes to a Wednesday. I tried reordering `wkdaylevels`, but it still misaligns. Linked data in the main question.

Comment: Use `factor(weekdays(slp$Date),levels=wkdaylevels)`. If you are using a different locale than english, you may need `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "english")` before.